# Fixing vertical spacing after \captionof as a custom caption

Tags: spacing, listings, captions, parcolumns

I'm trying to get a single caption after two columns of code. For two columns, `parcolumns` is the only method I've found that allows a page break in the middle and is my current favorite. Using minipages is also possible and looks a lot nicer until it forces ugly whitespace when it can't flow across multiple pages.

Anyway, my main problem is the vertical space after captionof, which I'm attempting to use as a caption of *both* columns. Below is an example where this happens. **How can I restore a normal spacing/margin after `\captionof`?**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}

\lstset{
    frame=lrtb,
    captionpos=b,
}

\begin{document}

An initial paragraph.

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Insertion sort using swaps}]
for i ← 1 to length(A)
    j ← i
    while j > 0 and A[j-1] > A[j]
        swap A[j] and A[j-1]
        j ← j - 1
\end{lstlisting}
A paragraph after lstlistings with normal indentation and vertical spacing.

\begingroup
%\noindent %this would cause extra vertical space before the parcolumns
\begin{parcolumns}[colwidths={1=.48\linewidth}]{2} %colwidths still leaves too much whitespace between columns
\footnotesize

\colchunk[1]{
\begin{lstlisting}
for i ← 1 to length(A)
    j ← i
    while j > 0 and A[j-1] > A[j]
        swap A[j] and A[j-1]
        j ← j - 1
\end{lstlisting}
}

\colchunk[2]{
\begin{lstlisting}
for i ← 1 to length(A)
    x ← A[i]
    j ← i
    while j > 0 and A[j-1] > x
        A[j] ← A[j-1]
        j ← j - 1
    A[j] ← x
\end{lstlisting}
}

\end{parcolumns}
\captionof{lstlisting}{Different insertion sorts in parcolumns.}
\endgroup

A paragraph after the caption for the parcolumns environment.
This paragraph is indented due to begingroup/endgroup but still has no vertical space/margin between
it and the caption.


\begingroup
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{.48\textwidth} %t aligns top
\footnotesize
\begin{lstlisting}
for i ← 1 to length(A)
    j ← i
    while j > 0 and A[j-1] > A[j]
        swap A[j] and A[j-1]
        j ← j - 1
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.48\textwidth}
\footnotesize
\begin{lstlisting}
for i ← 1 to length(A)
    x ← A[i]
    j ← i
    while j > 0 and A[j-1] > x
        A[j] ← A[j-1]
        j ← j - 1
    A[j] ← x
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\captionof{lstlisting}{Different insertion sorts in minipages.}
\endgroup

A paragraph after the caption for two minipages.
This paragraph is indented due to noindent and begingroup/endgroup but still has no vertical space/margin between
it and the caption.

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

(I'm not using frames on my lstlistings so the rendering bug isn't a problem, I hope)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a better method. Since both `listings` and `caption` packages act on `lstlisting`s' captions, it is better to nullify the spacing introduced by `listings` between the listing and the text after it, by adding `belowskip=0pt` in the `\lstset`:

```
\lstset{
    frame=lrtb,
    captionpos=b,
    belowskip=0pt
}
```

Then we set captions properties through `\captionsetup`

```
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{aboveskip=5pt,belowskip=\baselineskip}
```

In this way you have the same spacing either before and after the captions.

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}

\lstset{
    frame=lrtb,
    captionpos=b,
    belowskip=0pt
}

\captionsetup[lstlisting]{aboveskip=5pt,belowskip=\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

An initial paragraph.

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Insertion sort using swaps}]
for i ← 1 to length(A)
    j ← i
    while j > 0 and A[j-1] > A[j]
        swap A[j] and A[j-1]
        j ← j - 1
\end{lstlisting}
A paragraph after lstlistings with normal indentation and vertical spacing.

\begingroup
%\noindent %this would cause extra vertical space before the parcolumns
\begin{parcolumns}[colwidths={1=.48\linewidth}]{2} %colwidths still leaves too much whitespace between columns
\footnotesize

\colchunk[1]{
\begin{lstlisting}
for i ← 1 to length(A)
    j ← i
    while j > 0 and A[j-1] > A[j]
        swap A[j] and A[j-1]
        j ← j - 1
\end{lstlisting}
}

\colchunk[2]{
\begin{lstlisting}
for i ← 1 to length(A)
    x ← A[i]
    j ← i
    while j > 0 and A[j-1] > x
        A[j] ← A[j-1]
        j ← j - 1
    A[j] ← x
\end{lstlisting}
}

\end{parcolumns}
\captionof{lstlisting}{Different insertion sorts in parcolumns.}
\endgroup

A paragraph after the caption for the parcolumns environment.
This paragraph is indented due to begingroup/endgroup but still has no vertical space/margin between
it and the caption.


\begingroup
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{.48\textwidth} %t aligns top
\footnotesize
\begin{lstlisting}
for i ← 1 to length(A)
    j ← i
    while j > 0 and A[j-1] > A[j]
        swap A[j] and A[j-1]
        j ← j - 1
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.48\textwidth}
\footnotesize
\begin{lstlisting}
for i ← 1 to length(A)
    x ← A[i]
    j ← i
    while j > 0 and A[j-1] > x
        A[j] ← A[j-1]
        j ← j - 1
    A[j] ← x
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\captionof{lstlisting}{Different insertion sorts in minipages.}
\endgroup

A paragraph after the caption for two minipages.
This paragraph is indented due to noindent and begingroup/endgroup but still has no vertical space/margin between
it and the caption.

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]